Hölder's condition and Fourier transform
For Fourier Transform of function $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ there are such constants $\alpha\in(0,1), C>0$ such that $|\hat{f}(y)|\le\frac{C}{(1+|y|)^{\alpha+1}} \forall y \in \mathbb{R}$. prove that function $f$ satisfies Hölder's condition with $\alpha$:
$f(x_1)-f(x_2) \le C(x_1-x_2)^{\alpha}$
I've solved similar task when it was said that $f$ holds given inequality and I needed to prove that $\hat{f}(y)$ satisfies Hölder's condition. I've solved it by adjusting the definition like that: $f(x+t)-f(x)\le Cx^{\alpha}.$ But here I have troubles with writing inequalities because there will be subtraction of integrals and it is not clear how to properly estimate it (we can not estimate each minuend and subtrahend the same way)...

I guess Fourier transform is an involution i.e. $F(F(f)) = f$ under some conditions.

The inequality should be written as $|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \leq C |x_1 - x_2|^\alpha$. A good place to start would be to write each $f$ as the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat f$ and then the difference as a single integral.

@TrevorNorton, I give up. I followed your advice and got $\int_{\mathbb{R}}{\hat{f(y)}}(e^{x_1iy}-e^{x_2iy})dy \le \int_{\mathbb{R}}{|\hat{f(y)}|}(|e^{x_1iy}|+|e^{x_2iy}|)dy \le 2 \cdot 2 \int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(1+y)^{1+\alpha}}dy} = \frac{4}{\alpha}$ the problem is that I have no $|x_1-x_2|$ and can not estimate $\frac{4}{\alpha} \le \frac{4}{\alpha} \cdot |x_1-x_2|^{\alpha}$ because $\alpha \in (0, 1)$

@Salcio, followed your advice too. please see my comment above

@JaneDoe I've posted a solution to this problem. Does it help?

@TrevorNorton, yes, much obliged! My solution was almost the same except of the substitution on the last step, thank you!

Let's define $t = |x_1 - x_2|$ and assume $t>0$ (the case where $t=0$ is obvious). Then
$$ \begin{align} |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | &\leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty |e^{i x_1 y} - e^{ix_2 y}| |\hat f(y)|\,\mathrm d y \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty |e^{i t y} - 1| |\hat f(y)|\,\mathrm d y \\
&\leq C \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{|e^{ity} -1 |}{(1 + |y|)^{\alpha +1}}\,\mathrm d y.
\end{align}$$
Now doing a change of variables with $z= ty$ gives that the last integral is equal to
$$ t^\alpha \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{|e^{iz} - 1|}{(t+|z|)^{\alpha +1}}\, \mathrm d z \leq t^\alpha \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{|e^{iz} - 1|}{|z|^{\alpha +1}}\, \mathrm d z.$$
Note that the integral after the final inequality is finite since the integrand is $\sim |z|^{-(\alpha +1)}$ as $|z|\to\infty$ and $\sim|z|^{-\alpha}$ as $|z|\to 0$. Thus putting it all together we have
$$ |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | \leq C t = C |x_1 - x_2|. $$
